# Have to display the number of times an element has been added in my map JAVA

Tags: java, collections, treemap

I've created a `TreeMap` with products.

And I want to count the number of times they repeat themselves, but have no clue what to code. Any hints? (I expect **no** code, just suggestions)

```
private static Map<Integer, String> shoppingCart() {
    Map<Integer, String> result = new TreeMap<>();
    result.put(1, "sausage");
    result.put(2, "sausage");
    result.put(3, "soup");
    result.put(4, "egg");
    result.put(5, "egg");
    result.put(6, "tomato");
    result.put(7, "sausage");
    
    return result;
}
```

I was thinking about adding a counting variable, but still it doesn't fix the repeating problem.

Comment: why not go through all of them and count the repeated ones?

Comment: You want to count the number of times a  _value_ value was added to the map? So, "sausage" would be there 3 times, with 3 different key values?

Comment: Maybe you should tell us more about what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: yeap, exactly this, still trying to understand what you've all meant

Answer (score 9):

Maybe not the best approach, but without modifying what you already have, you could use another map to store the products as keys and the quantity as the value for those keys:

```
Map<Integer, String> result = shoppingCart();
Map<String, Integer> productQuantities = new HashMap<>();

result.values().forEach(value -> 
    productQuantities.put(value,productQuantities.getOrDefault(value, 0) + 1));
```

To print the resulting map:

```
productQuantities.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + ":" + value));
```

Comment: Depends on what you want to accomplish. You can create another method and just add it all there, or you can just do everything inside main(). Do you just need to display the information?

Comment: just have to practise methods topic, so id rather do it like that, instead of in main method, anyway i just put those things into my method and called out the productQuantities, Had to overview this anyway

Comment: Agreed, edited to make it cleaner

Answer (score 4):

> I created a TreeMap with products, and i want to count the number of times they repeat themselves

Probably a different type of `Map` with *keys* representing *items* and *values* representing the corresponding *count* would be more handy. Something like:

```
NavigableMap<String, Integer> countByItem
```

***Note:*** in order to access methods of the `TreeMap` like `ceilingKey()`, `floorKey()`, `higherEntry()`, `lowerEntry()`, etc. which are not defined in the `Map` interface you need to use [`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html) as a type.

And it might make sense to make the *item* to be a *custom object*, instead of being a `String`. That would guard you from making typo, and it provides a possibility to gives useful behavior to `Item`

```
public class Item {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    
    // constructor, getters, equals/hashCode, ect.
}
```

That's how map of items can be updated using Java 8 method [`merge()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#merge(K,V,java.util.function.BiFunction)), which expects a *key*, a *value* and a *function* responsible for merging the *old value* and the *new one*:

```
NavigableMap<Item, Integer> countByItem = new TreeMap<>(Comparator.comparingInt(Item::getId));
        
countByItem.merge(new Item(1, "sausage"),1, Integer::sum);
countByItem.merge(new Item(1, "sausage"),1, Integer::sum);
countByItem.merge(new Item(2, "soup"),1, Integer::sum);
```

If you don't feel very comfortable with Java 8 functions, instead of `merge()` you can use combination of methods `put()` & [`getOrDefault()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault(java.lang.Object,V)):

```
Item sausage = new Item(1, "sausage");

countByItem.put(sausage, countByItem.getOrDefault(sausage, 0) + 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

I can only guess at your goal. In your `Map <Integer, String>`, what does the `Integer` represent? Product number? Quantity? Sequence number? Something else?

If the `Integer` represents quantity, you have it backwards. It should be `Map <String, Integer>`. In a `Map<X,Y>`, the `X` represents the key. A `Map` allows fast lookup by the key. The `Y` is the value -- the information you want to find for a particular key, if the key is in the Map.

For example, if you want to add "sausage", you want to check if it is in the Map. If it isn't, put it into the Map with quantity 1. If it is, retrieve it and update the quantity.

If the `Integer` represents a sequence number (1st item, 2nd item, 3rd item, ...), you don't need a `Map`. Consider using an array or a data structure that preserves order, such as a `List`.

However, using an array or `List` still leaves you with the problem of how find how many of each item are in the list, when duplicates are allowed, as they are in your problem. To solve that, consider a `Map<String, Integer>` where the `Integer` (map value) is the quantity, and the `String` (map key) is the product name.

If I were doing this, I'd create classes to allow me to glue together related information. Here is part of a hypothetical example, which might be more realistic than you need:

```
public class Product {
    private int upc;  // product code, often represented with bar code
    private Decimal price; 
    private String description;
    private String shortDescription;
    private ProductClass prodClass; // department, taxable, etc.
    // etc. -- add needed fields, or remove irrelevant 
    // constructors, getters, setters,
```

Override `.equals` and `.hashcode` in `Product`. You use the UPC for those.

If you use `implements Comparable<Product>`, you have the possibility of using binary search, or a search tree.

```
public class Receipt {
    private Decimal total;
    private Decimal taxableTotal;
    private Map <Product,Integer> shoppingCart; // Product, Quantity 
    // etc.
```

When each item is scanned, you can lookup the Product in the Map, and add it if not found, or update the quantity if found, as in the previous answers.